# Push notifications to the user in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Does some package or pattern for push notifications for users in Meteor already exist? So I would like to have some way for server to send a notification to the user which is then displayed to the user. Is there something already there? Or should I just create a collection of notifications and get client to subscribe to it, displaying anything which is there as it gets pushed?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment as far as I know theres no way to subscribe to something thats not a collection so to push custom data like a push notification down to the user you would need to use a notification collection.

On your client side you can have an observer that listens for new notifications

```
Notifications.find().observe({
    added:function(document): {
        //Push notify your client
        Notifications.remove(document._id); //Remove when viewed
    }
});
```

A really nice library to display these on the client is : http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/ you could have it pop up as soon as you insert something into the notifications collection